# how to create simple image slider / accordion ?

Tags: jquery, image, slider, jquery-animate, accordion

In wordpress pages is there a plugin for vertical images..

I want a web page which should look like as follows:

[image]

In this there a main panel **Products** .And which has images as accordions..

Only 10% of the image is visible..but onclick of the **image1** It should expand 100% as follows :

[image]

And the main thing is..These images user should be able to put in **WP  pages**

Static its possible ..as shown in [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/22/vertical-sliding-accordion/)

but i want it to be edited in the page or ..some othe way ..may be in one folder..

Is it possible?
Is there a plugin which will help me out ?
or else if i need to code for that then 
can anyone give me idea regarding same...?

Comment: if you want to do it with css3, here is perfect example for you: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ImageAccordion/

Comment: thanks barlasapaydin..its horizontal sliding of images..
i want same but vertical..i am new to coding in jquery..plzz..

Comment: yes yes was trying..i almost got it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your simple jQuery slider/accordion:

[You can inspect from here (jsfiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/14/)

jQuery:

```
$('div').bind({
  click: function() {
    $('div').stop().animate({'height':'100px'},600);//600 sets time. 600miliseconds
    $(this).stop().animate({'height':'320px'},600);
  },
  /* if you want to do it with hover effects, just deactive click and use these:
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('div').stop().animate({'height':'100px'},600);//600 sets time. 600miliseconds
    $(this).stop().animate({'height':'320px'},600);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('div').stop().animate({'height':'100px'},600);
  }
  */
});​
```

html:

```
<div>
   <img src="http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/_np/7181/17287181.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
   <img src="http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/_np/2790/17282790.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
   <img src="http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/_np/6751/17286751.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
   <img src="http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/_np/7203/17287203.jpg" />
</div>
```

css:

```
div { overflow:hidden; float:left; height:100px; margin:0 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }  ​
```

Note: You can use this on everything, just need to initialise jQuery (:

Comment: the above code displays the images but on mouse hover it doesnt get maximized....:(

Comment: got to go mate sorry, need to eat something (: but you can handle this.