# Remove JQuery accordion behavior?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a requirement to display content with an accordion or without. Is there a way to easily add and remove the accordion behavior? In other words, can I revert the styles and behaviors applied to my divs to a state before they were "accordionized"?

Comment: if you want to create your accordion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556127/how-to-create-simple-image-slider-accordion/11556641#11556641

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the destroy method.

```
$("#accordion").accordion("destroy")
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-destroy

most if not all official jQuery UI widgets have this method.